# Looking for FTPS Example - NOT the Commons.Net one

Tags: class, ftp

i still got the Problem, that my Java Interpreter can't handle SSL Handshake from a FTPS Client Connection. So I want to try out another FTPS Class that cann store a File on a FTP Server.

Do you know any other Examples/Classes than the Commons.Net one ?

Thank you, Louis

Comment: Why don't you rather get the problem with Commons Net fixed?

Comment: I tried really everything, but i dont get it working. You can check my other questions and you will see...

Comment: You should have tagged them "ftp" to get the questions to an audience you need.